# Html element changes position when the page is refreshed in chrome

Tags: html, css, position

I'm using chrome and when I go to this page the menu is not visible. The menu is the 3 lines button at the top right. If you go now and open the inspector the element is hidden because is above the header. Now if you refresh the page the menu is correctly positioned. Also happens in chromium. The page in question is: http://playszone.com/ (Don't click on the link, read below)

**In order to reproduce the problem you should not click on the link. Open a new tab and copy paste the url. Then refresh the page.**

If you go to inspector and disable and enable the position on the `body > .wrapper > header > .icons` it will show at the right place. I really cannot understand what is making the page to wrongly position the element, only when open in a new tab and write the site url.

What is the problem? Is my fault or what?

Comment: Very weird, especially because it works properly when just clicking the link.

Comment: Yes, never happened to be before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this, it fixes it. `bottom: 1px`

```
.icons {
display: inline-block;
height: 55px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 1px;
}
```

Or...

```
.icons {
display: inline-block;
height: 55px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will try and will give you feedback. Do you know the reason of this problem? why it happens, because it seems a bug in the browser.

Comment: I am thinking it has to be because of your position absolute. I am still searching through the DOM to come up with an explanation. It adding the bottom 1 fixes it but its ridiculous for it to change position on a refresh. I was thinking maybe it has to do with a div not being closed but validator does not find that issue...

Comment: Actually yes it is the position absolute. If you take the position absolute out and just float right instead it fixes it as well.

Comment: I'm still interested to know why this happen. Can you explain a little bit about it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not in the right place. It's in the "same place" in the code, but when you hover the code of the "icons" div, it shows you on the page that it's actually a little bit lower, behind your white menu and since the menu is probably rendered on top of it, you can't see it.

A quick fix would probably be to set the "icons" div with absolute positionning and setting the position-top to 0px.

Comment: Yes, when I've said "not in the right place" I've been refering to the visual placement. I will try your solution

Comment: It probably has to do with the order in which things are rendered pre-and post-cache but I can't figure out why at a first glance at the code.